# Trying to join 3 pictures

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am analysing images from accelerated ageing tests. I would like to display this cumulative sum of electrical discharges that happened on the surface on a diagram of what that setup of electrodes and total sample was like for reference.

Total size of the picture is equal to the size of the sample. It is a rectangle 5cm by 120cm. This is the cumulative image.

[image]

In the cumulative plot the aspects are less rectangular as all activity happens between electrodes so when previously summing frames I rejected areas that were not between electrodes in order to improve performance.

This image was generated with matplotlib with jet colouring. As such it was originally a data matrix. In order to add it to the reference picture I have saved this image as png and reloaded it. This operation changed the aspect ratio slightly but I resized it correctly later.

I have used this function to add to a white rectangle with the dimensions same as the raw footage. Initially I added scaled both top and bottom electrodes to the white background image.

```
def overlay(background_img, img_to_overlay_t, x, y, negpos, overlay_size=None):

    bg_img = background_img.copy()

    if overlay_size is not None:
        img_to_overlay_t = cv.resize(img_to_overlay_t.copy(), overlay_size)

    # Extract the alpha mask of the RGBA image, convert to RGB 
    b,g,r,a = cv.split(img_to_overlay_t)
    overlay_color = cv.merge((b,g,r))

    # Apply some simple filtering to remove edge noise
    mask = cv.medianBlur(a,5)

    #mask = np.zeros(source_img.shape[:2], np.uint8)
    h, w, _ = overlay_color.shape
    roi = bg_img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    ## works sort of but with removed details
    #mask = mask.astype(np.int8)        

    # Black-out the area behind the logo in our original ROI
    img1_bg = cv.bitwise_and(roi.copy(),roi.copy(),mask = cv.bitwise_not(mask))

    # Mask out the logo from the logo image.
    img2_fg = cv.bitwise_and(overlay_color,overlay_color,mask = mask)

    img2_fg = img2_fg.astype(np.float32)
    img1_bg = img1_bg.astype(np.float32)

    if negpos == False:
        bg_img[y:y+h, x:x+w] = cv.subtract(img1_bg, img2_fg)
    else:
        bg_img[y:y+h, x:x+w] = cv.add(img1_bg, img2_fg)


    return bg_img
```

It yields this diagram.
[image]

Everything worked fine up until this point. Problem was trying to add cumulative in between the electrodes. My issue comes with being unable to slot that cumulative plot into the reference layout image of the electrodes and total sample size. I get

`OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed ((mtype == 0 || mtype == 1) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1))`

at

`img1_bg = cv.bitwise_and(roi.copy(),roi.copy(),mask = cv.bitwise_not(mask))`

I can fix that by casting mask to uint8 or int8
`mask = mask.astype(np.uint8)`

This has it's own issues as the blue discharge part ends up lossing all the features and basically consists of 3 different colours only.

This the outcome I'd like to have displayed/saved at the end. I've no idea how to get to it.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, what if you use something like phototshop, sketch, online free alternative? Is there reason to do it programmatically.

Comment: It is part of the larger package. It will be used for extracting data from experiments with different setup. It would be inconvenient for the user to have to do it especially many times.

Comment: Can you, please, provide a [MCVE] along with the input images you feed to this function?